# Disabling FileSystemWatcher for specific updates?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

Does anyone have any ideas how I can reliably disable a FileSystemWatcher object when my application makes changes to the files in the directory, so that I am only watching for *external* changes to the directory?

I've tried setting `EnableRaisingEvents` to false immediately before performing a write and setting it back to true immediately after, but it seems this method is not reliable, and occasionally I still get the event firing.

The only other thing I can think of is to wait a small amount of time after performing the write to let the OS finish up the modification of the directory before re-enabling the FSW, but that seems hackish and I don't like it.

---

To add to the problem, the directory consists of potentially many files, the identities of which are beyond my knowledge and control, so I can't just wait for the event to fire for a specific file and then ignore it. There could be any number of FSW events firing after a single modification (because of the potentially many files getting updated).

Comment: I don't understand why you can't ignore events for the files you're modifying - you'd know the path of the file you've modified, so why not just ignore events for that file for a short period of time after you've modified it?

Comment: could you set a NotifyFilter on the watcher to filter out the notifications ?

Comment: I've looked into NotifyFilter, but it's not that useful from what I can see. @Daniel, I don't know the specific file paths because they're created by a library out of my control (Lucene.net).

Comment: Maybe Lucene provides an event that could tell you which files it creates/modifies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this using the .NET API.

As multiple users pointed out, you'll probably be better off maintaining a list of changes you make and subtract them from the changeset you observe.

You can also use Win32-level API, which gives you a PID for the process making the change if I'm not mistaken (not sure about this, I've written a driver before which did this (and more) inside the kernel space).

UPDATE: I called someone on the team I worked with on this project, and they confirm we had the PID in kernel space only.

Comment: Now that would be great if I could determine the process--then I could just check if it was me or not. Do you recall the name of the hook or function in Win32?

Comment: Shachar, this doesn't appear to be the case. I see no mention of any way to obtain a process id using FindFirstChangeNotification or ReadDirectoryChangesW.

Now if I could somehow receive an event when my process obtains a file handle, I could check to see if that file was in the directory and ignore changes to it, but I can't find any way to do that, either. :(